# error while installing "time" package in Anaconda

Tags: python, time, anaconda, conda, python-3.7

When I tried to install time package in anaconda prompt using the command

**conda install -c conda-forge time**

I got the following error

[image]

How to resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/time) for the `time` package, you will see that `windows` is not an option there, only `linux` and `osx`.

[image]

And from your question it seems like you are working on `windows`.

Answer (score 0):

`time` is in the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) that is (usually) distributed with Python. Therefore, usually there is no (need to) install. You can directly `import time`.